# Are Amorphous enemies affected by nets if they're not immune to the restrained condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, conditions

Some creatures, like Black Puddings, have the Amorphous trait, meaning that they can move through very small spaces. But these creatures don't all have the restrained condition immunity.

What happens when you successfully throw a net at such an amorphous creature, provided that its not immune to the restrained condition? Will they be able to just move away from the net without any penality due to being amorphous, or will they suffer the Restrained condition as normally given by a net?

This assumes that the creature doesn't passively dissolve the net when it touches its skin, or some similar destructive effect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### The Amorphous Enemy is Not Affected

We know the following about nets from the item's description in the Player's Handbook (bold added):

> A net has no effect on creatures that are **formless**, or creatures that are Huge or larger. (PHB, p. 148).

Although "formless" isn't a tag or formal term (like "shapeshifter") which clearly applies to certain creatures and not others, we have a hint by how rarely it is used. The only time the word "formless" is used in the Monster Manual is in the following passage (bold added):

> The demon lord of slimes and oozes, Juiblex is a stew of noxious fluids that lurks in the abyssal depths. The wretched Faceless Lord cares nothing for cultists
>   or mortal servants, and its sole desire is to turn all creatures into **formless** copies of its horrid self. (MM, p. 52)

As such, we have evidence that oozes and slimes are intended to be considered "formless". And as such, nets will not affect them at all.

Comment: Ahhhh, a marvelous answer indeed ! Well, not for my net-wielding character, but marvelous in its explanation, heh !